# What is faster, subselect or distinct (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Let me describe my doubt. I have system where I have three entities, Doctor, Patient and Appointment. An appointment has the doctor's id and patient Id.

I need now to retrieve all the patients which have an appointment with a concrete doctor, and I'm not sure what will be faster, a distinct or a subselect for the id's, these are the queries:

using distinct->

```
SELECT DISTINCT patient.id, patient.name, patient.surname FROM
appointment INNER JOIN patient ON patient.id = appointment.patientid WHERE
appointment.doctorid = @id;
```

using subselect->

```
SELECT patient.id, patient.name, patient.surname FROM patient
WHERE patient.id IN (select appointment.patientid FROM appointment 
WHERE appointment.doctorid = @id);
```

Not sure it this will affect, the system will run on a MariaDB cluster.

Comment: Probably the first one. but you can add `EXPLAIN` before the `SELECT`  to see what indexes are being used (http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/mysql/operations)

Comment: Ok, I will try the explain, nice article by the way. Thanks.

Comment: Its never that easy to tell. Depending on how many columns your tables have and how many rows you are retrieving. Do you have a software to retrieve queries? Aqua Studio for example will show you a diagram of both queries and you can compare performance.

Comment: Actually I use DbForge community edition, but I see there is a trial of Aqua Studio,  I'm going to give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Just [Race Your Horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with any performance question, you should test on your data and your hardware.  The suspect problem in the first version the `DISTINCT` after the `JOIN`; this can require a lot of extra processing.

You can write the second as:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.surname
FROM patient p
WHERE p.id IN (select a.patientid FROM appointment a WHERE a.doctorid = @id);
```

For this, you want an index on `appointment(doctorid, patientid)`.

You might consider this version as well:

```
select p.id, p.name, p.surname
from patient p join
     (select distinct appointment.patientid
      from appointment
      where appointment.doctorid = @id
     ) a
     on p.id = a.patientid;
```

This specifically wants the same index.  This pushes the `distinct` so it is only operating on a single table, meaning that MySQL may be able to use the index for that operation.

And this one:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.surname
FROM patient p
WHERE EXISTS (select 1
              from appointment a
              where a.doctorid = @id and a.patientid = p.id
             );
```

This query wants an index on `appointment(patientid, doctorid)`.  It requires a full table scan of `patient` with a fast index lookup on each row.  That could often be the fastest approach, depending on the data.

Note:  which query performs better may also depends on the size and distribution of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

These suffer from "inflate-deflate".  That is, the `JOIN` leads to more rows in a temp table, only to prune back to what you need.  This is costly.  (And it can give wrong answers for `COUNT` and `SUM`.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ... JOIN ...
and
SELECT ... JOIN ... GROUP BY ...
```

This performs poorly because of optimizer limitations:

```
... IN ( SELECT ... )
```

This is what you want:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT id FROM ... WHERE ... )
    JOIN ...
```

It is especially good if the subquery needs `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, and/or `LIMIT`.  This is because it will create a small set of rows before doing the `JOIN`, thereby decreasing the number of `JOINs` needed.

Answer (score -1):

I think The appointment should have an id to join through ... so here is a code ... I hope it helps

```
SELECT patient.id, patient.name, patient.surname FROM patient
INNER JOIN appointment ON appointment.id = patient.patientid 
INNER JOIN doctor ON doctor.id = appointment.id
WHERE appointment.doctorid = @id
```

Comment: Hmmm, that will give me duplicates if a patient has more than an appointment with a doctor, no?

Comment: Also, it should be `INNER JOIN doctor ON doctor.id = appointment.doctorid`

Comment: yes ... I think this is a better connection for your tables ... to connect the appointment for the doctor and the patient

Comment: Not better, the only, there's no relation between the doctor's id and the appointment id...